# Pronunciation of えい

Tags: pronunciation

Back to basics: I was certain the pronunciation of えい (like in せんせい) was "ee" (except in few cases like in スペイン), I've read that everywhere.

But in one of the few French reference books for learning Japanese, they say it's pronounced "e-i" like the English words "say", "may", "day".

So I was wondering if it is a HUGE mistake of that book, or if it's more subtle than that?

And maybe the same happens with おう?

Thanks.

Comment: @siikamiika Wow. That link destroys everything I've always thought about えい. Especially on 先生. I've always been told saying [sensei] instead of [sensee] is a huge mistake. Damn.

Comment: It of course depends on who you ask. But in [Tokyo dialect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F#Pronunciation_2) it's "ee"

Comment: @siikamiika Yes that's the thing, absolutely every source I've read or heard, in French or in English, say as a basic rule that えい is pronounced [ee]. Except that book I was talking about.

Comment: Note that “say”, “may”, &c can be pronounced using a long monophthong in English, so the book can't be wrong, as such, just imprecise.